# Why do we get error with JRE 11 Mac OSX(amd64)

Tags: install4j

We created installer for Mac with bundled JRE Macosx(amd64) 11.0.1. When in our application we add to JPanel container another object extended from JComponent (BrowserView from JxBrowser), our application is crashing and Mac computer shows Error page with message that is not found class sun/lwawt/LWComponentPeer.

JxBrowser support says that on Mac JDK 11 from Oracle there are not any issues.

Is it possible that sun/lwawt/LWComponentPeer is not presented in JRE Macosx(amd64) 11.0.1 ? What JRE should we use instead?

(Question also sent to install4j support)

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 9, the JRE is modularized and you cannot access classes that are not exported by modules. To access this particular class, the VM parameter

```
--add-exports java.desktop/sun.lwawt=ALL-UNNAMED
```

would have to be passed to the JVM. This may just trigger the next exception and
you have to work your way forward.